# Using MAAS to deploy graphical shell on office workstations

Tags: maas, desktop-environments, pxe, disk-image

Would it be possible to deploy desktop images to my office workstations from MAAS?

I would like to see a scenario in which the workstations have a graphical shell and some PXE boot KVM instances ready to be deployed. I understand there is a possibility that one experiences severe performance penalties for some processes like maybe the GUI itself, but that's not of interest to me at the moment.

I can imagine a few paths to go about and give you an impression:

- Create a custom deployment image. And deploy it to a cluster.
- Add some extra details to the commissioning/deploy script.
- Create a juju charm that contains a desktop and assign it to each machine within the maas zone.

But these are just ideas. How would I go about it?

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this thread. https://bugs.launchpad.net/curtinator/+bug/1864033

Answer (score 4):

`curtinator`[a] could help you to customized Ubuntu desktop images that could be deployed by MAAS.

Please go to [a] and download the `curtinator` source by `bzr`. The `README` of the curtinator project source should be sufficient to guide you to make a MAAS-deployable Ubuntu desktop image and be imported by MAAS. However, please let me illustrate the "too detailed"[b] steps for you according to the README. I have tested these steps on MAAS 2.1.3 with Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.1 desktop images. You could skip the following steps if you think the README is enough to you.

### Prepare the Environment

1. I tested these steps on my Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.1 Desktop system.
2. `sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin virt-viewer genisoimage`
3. Reboot the system after you have installed the above packages.
4. `bzr branch lp:curtinator` to fetch the curtinator source (you may need to install bzr by `sudo apt-get install bzr`) somewhere, say `<curtinator root>`
5. Download an Ubuntu desktop image. In this case, we choose `ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` and put it in `<curtinator root>`

### Use curtinator

1. Go to the downloaded curtinator source `<curtinator root>`
2. In `<curtinator root>`, execute `./scripts/curtinator ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`
3. If everything works well, you will get a tarball `ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.tar.gz` in `<curtinator root>`.

The console message looks like:

```
$ ./scripts/curtinator ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
Extracting ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso to ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64
Creating ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64/casper/preseed.cfg
Patching ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64/casper/initrd.lz with ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64/casper/preseed.cfg
Creating ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64/root.qcow2
Creating ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64/libvirt.xml
Starting domain ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64
Domain ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64 defined from ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64/libvirt.xml

Domain ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64 started

Installing, run this command for progress:
# virt-viewer ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64
Compressing tarball
Finished ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.tar.gz
```

Please note the relative path is important when executing curtinator.

### Upload the Customized Ubuntu 16.04.1 desktop image

1. `scp ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.tar.gz <your MAAS server>`
2. On your MAAS server (mine is MAAS 2.1.3.x), execute `maas $YOUR_MAAS_PROFILE boot-resources create -d name=<YOUR_CUSOMIZED_ISO_NAME> architecture=amd64/generic filetype=tgz content@=<where your ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.tar.gz is>`.

In my case, it is

```
maas askubuntuprofile boot-resources create -d name=custome_desktop_16-04-01 architecture=amd64/generic filetype=tgz content@=/home/ubuntu/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.tar.gz
```

`YOUR_CUSOMIZED_ISO_NAME` is a label name that will show on your MAAS dashboard when you selects which image you want to deploy. In my case, it is `custome_desktop_16-04-01`. You can see that there is a customized image which is syncing in the following MAAS dashboard screenshot.

[image: Syncing to rack controllers]

Wait for few minutes until it is synced.

[image]

Now you can deploy this customized desktop image as usual. Select the tab `Custom` and your customized desktop image name like this:

[image]

---

[a] https://launchpad.net/curtinator

[b] Too much detailed so I won't update the README ; )

Comment: amazing!  really helpful

Answer (score 2):

two ways - you could create an image for mass that has desktop, or, in your charm, in your install hook, you include

```
sudo apt-get install <desktoppackagename>
```

Where

```
sudo aptitude install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

Personally, I think the charm is the easiest way.  Help received from this answer:
[How to install GUI desktop on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2093/how-to-install-gui-desktop-on-a-server)

Comment: I agree. However, I wasn't sure it would be possible, since the normal screen of a juju booted machine shows a continues text screen from cloud-init. I will dive into the charm tools to create such a charm and see if it will work.
Thanks for you input.